# Dynamic token generation before deployment in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, jwt

I am fairly new to kubernetes and learning kubernetes deployments from scratch. For a microservice based projecct that I am working on, each microservice has to authenticate with their own client-id and client-secret to the auth server, before requesting any information (JWT). These ids and secrets are required for each services and needs to be in their environment variables. Initially the auth service will generate those ids and secrets via database seeds. What is the best way in the world of kubernetes to automatically set this values in the environments of a pod deployment before pod creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how automatic you want it to be. A simple approach would be an initContainer to provision a new token, put that in a shared volume file, and then an entrypoint script in the main container which reads the file and sets the env var.

The problem with that is authenticating the initContainer is hard. The big hammer solution would be to write a custom operator to manage this but if you're new to Kubernetes that's going to be super hard and probably overkill anyway.

Comment: I have implemented the entrypoint stuff, but could not find any resource to set env var. Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: `bash -c "eval /volume/value.sh && exec myapp"` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I tried this but the env value is never setting. 

My value.sh file is something like this:

"export APP_CLIENT_ID=somevalue
export APP_CLIENT_SECRET=somevalue".

when the container starts and I exec into it and run printenv APP_CLIENT_ID, i get no values. 

Do you have any work around?

Comment: Add `set -x` to the bootstrap script and see what it runs.